# Simple COSMOSDB query from DataBricks problems

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, databricks, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am writing a replacement PySpark routine for a pydocumentdb library based function that no longer works due to the pydocumentdb library being deprecated.  The function call just looks like this `def QueryCosmos (container, query, schema, target)` I have not interacted with COSMOS before but I feel it should be a fairly simple task, but whichever approach I take I seem to hit a snag. The 3 approaches I have tried are :

- Using the COSMOS SDK
- Using the COSMOS Connector
- Using the COSMOS Catalog API

I'm sure its due to my inexperience but I feel I am missing something somewhere.

Firstly the libraries I have set up on the cluster are as follows:
[image]

Line 2 full path (com.azure.cosmos.spark:azure-cosmos-spark_3-2_2-12:4.10.0)

Code for SDK variant

```
#cosmos db libraries

import azure.cosmos.cosmos_client as cosmos_client
import azure.cosmos.exceptions as exceptions
from azure.cosmos.partition_key import PartitionKey
import os
import json

def QueryCosmos_example (container, query, schema, target):

  #get the connection settings
  Env = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "AzureKeyVault", key = "xxxxxxxx")
  CosmosAddress = "https://xxxxxxxxxxx" + Env + ".documents.azure.com:443/"
  CosmosSecretKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "AzureKeyVault", key = "xxxxxxxxxxx")

  #get the container link
  database = "dbs/xxxxxx-cosmosdb-01-" + Env
  collection = database + "/colls/" + container

  #perform query
  client = cosmos_client.CosmosClient(CosmosAddress, {'masterKey': CosmosSecretKey} )
  print(CosmosAddress)  
  
  db = client.get_database_client(database)
  cont = db.get_container_client(container)
  print(cont)

  test_query="select * from c WHERE c.id = '245655b424852a89ea75ebe7fdf812df9de4e6220cdeba1489597ce6d1cd686d'" 
    
  items = list(cont.query_items(
        query=test_query,
        enable_cross_partition_query=True
    ))

  print(items)

  #convert to data frame
  df = spark.createDataFrame(items, schema=schema)
 
  
  #create a temp view based on the results
  df.createOrReplaceTempView(target)
```

The code above has been altered to remove sensitive information. However as you can see from the output below the container information is coming through, so it just seems by query call is incorrect though looking around I cant see a fault with it.

[image]

Is there a way to see what the request is from DataBricks, or more information about what the Response contains. I am assuming it might contain further exception information...

The COSMOS connector code is:

```
..........
 database = "xxxxxxxxxxxx" + Env
# The code above here is same as the previous snippet

 test_query= "select * from c WHERE c.id = '245655b424852a89ea75ebe7fdf812df9de4e6220cdeba1489597ce6d1cd686d'"
  cfg = {
    "spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint" : CosmosAddress,
    "spark.cosmos.accountKey" : CosmosSecretKey,
    "spark.cosmos.database" : database,
    "spark.cosmos.container" : container,
    "spark.cosmos.read.customQuery" : test_query
    
  }
  
  item = spark.read.format("cosmos.oltp").options(**cfg).load()
  item.createOrReplaceTempView("supporter")
  display(item)
```

When I run it can't find the data, however if I run the query in the portal I get results returned .

[image]

Many thanks
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have managed to find the issue.

Looking at the first example , when you look at the container address returned its :
[image]

You can see that the dbs path level is repeated. The code snippet was taken directly from the pydocumentdb code, so this is a slight inconsistency between the two library calls.

The original database reference was:

```
database = "dbs/xxxxxx-cosmosdb-01-" + Env
```

Corrected reference

```
database = "xxxxxx-cosmosdb-01-" + Env
```